# Python permutations in order

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
listA = ["A","B","C","D"]
```

From this, I want the following output only:

```
["A","B","C"]
["B","C","D"]
["C","D","A"]
["D","A","B"]
```

I have looked at various questions on permutations here, but I am not able to do achieve this so far. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Following output doesn't contain  all permutations all of your set so title is missleading. What are you looking for is called combinations.

Comment: @iklinac It's not permutations or combinations, at least not in the conventional way they are defined (and applied in `itertools`)

Comment: Yes itertools define them bit different (even though order doesn't matter) but in general this is cyclic slicing of 3 elements in worst case  title can say combinations. Nowhere near permutations as there are 24 permutations for following set.

Comment: @iklinac Yes it is a very small slice from all the permutations.. I myself wondered for a while what to title this question. Thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

another way to do this - brute force,

```
def permutation(L):
    for i in range(len(L)):
        x = L[i:i+3]
        length = len(x)
        if length != 3:
            x = x + L[:3-length]
        print(x)


L = ["A","B","C","D"]
permutation(L)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `itertools.cycle` and `itertools.islice`.

To get the order you show (as [@tobias_k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1639625/tobias-k) suggested):

```
>>> from itertools import cycle, islice
>>> listA = ["A","B","C","D"]
>>> [list(islice(cycle(listA), i, i+3)) for i in range(len(listA))]
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['B', 'C', 'D'], ['C', 'D', 'A'], ['D', 'A', 'B']]
```

To get an alternative sequential ordering:

```
>>> it = cycle(listA)
>>> [list(islice(it,3)) for _ in range(len(listA))]
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'A', 'B'], ['C', 'D', 'A'], ['B', 'C', 'D']]
```

Comment: Or `[list(islice(cycle(listA), i, i+3)) for i in range(len(listA))]` to get exactly the order from the question.

Comment: Another way to get your original ordering: `zip(*[iter(chain(*repeat(lst, 3)))] * 3)`

Comment: @tobias_k Yes, or perhaps `zip(*[chain.from_iterable(repeat(lst, 3))] * 3)`

Comment: Ah, of course. The extra call to `iter` isn't necessary in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your answers. I received one another answer from a friend that I wanted to share here. It goes like this.

```
listA = ["A","B","C","D"]
listB = listA + [listA[0]] + [listA[1]]

catch = []
for i in range(len(listA)):
    A = listB[i]
    B = listB[i+1]
    C = listB[i+2]
    catch.append([A,B,C])
print catch
```